# Schengen Visa: Is presenting at an academic conference classified as business?

Tags: schengen, terminology, conferences

I intend to apply for a Schengen Visa to present at a railway conference. I will be presenting on behalf of my current employer.

I wish to know if this would be classified as business/work and would I need to submit a different application as compared to the standard Schengen application.

Thanks,
Kamil

Comment: The application is the same; you simply select a different option for "main purpose of the journey" (number 21).